# How to call the classes in different pages in selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium

I have created two classes that read data from different Excel sheets in selenium So how to Create object and call the second class using java without giving any data from the the script.

In second class has parameters.I want to get those data from Excel sheet without giving any data from class files. When I have created like below codes it did not run correctly.It shows this error:

```
"Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [successfullycreaterate] 
with [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, 
class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, 
class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, 
class java.lang.String]."
```

1. The first class

   ```
       @Test(dataProvider = "excelData")
       public void read(String username,String password) throws InterruptedException {

           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


           //handle popup window
           Set<String> windowId = driver.getWindowHandles();    // get  window id of current window
            Iterator<String> itererator = windowId.iterator();   

            String mainWinID = itererator.next();
            String  newAdwinID = itererator.next();

            driver.switchTo().window(newAdwinID);
            System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            Thread.sleep(3000);



            WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,3);

            WebElement uname= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath( "//input[@id='j_username']")));
            uname.sendKeys(username);

            WebElement pwd= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath( "//*[@id=\"j_password\"]")));
            pwd.sendKeys(password);

            WebElement login= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btnLogin\"]"));
            login.click();


       }
       @Test
       public void successfullycreaterate(String rateplan, String date, String hotel, String datevalidfrm, String datevalidto, String ratecatagory, String setcurrency, String taxlevel, String channel, String childlevel) throws IOException, InterruptedException   {
           CreateRate execute=new CreateRate();
           execute.successfullyCreate(rateplan, date, hotel, datevalidfrm, datevalidto, ratecatagory, setcurrency, taxlevel, channel, childlevel);

       } 


   }
   ```

2.The second class

```
@Test(dataProvider = "readExcelFile")
public void successfullyCreate(String rateplan,String date,String hotel,String datevalidfrm,String datevalidto,String ratecatagory,String setcurrency,String taxlevel,String channel,String childlevel ) throws  IOException, InterruptedException  {

    driver = DataProviderTest.setUp();
}

@DataProvider(name="readExcelFile")
public static Object[][] readExcelFile() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(resultFile);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

        System.out.println(sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
        System.out.println(sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
        int RowNum = sh.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        int ColNum = sh.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

        String[][] xlData = new String[RowNum-1][ColNum];

        for (int i = 0; i < RowNum - 1; i++) 
        {
            XSSFRow row = sh.getRow(i + 1);
            for (int j = 0; j < ColNum; j++) 
            {
                if (row == null)
                    xlData[i][j] = "";
                else {
                    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);                 
                    if (cell == null)
                        xlData[i][j] = ""; 
                    else {
                        String value = formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                        xlData[i][j] = value.trim();                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
        return xlData;
    }
```

It should be read data from the excel sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Samudi, The error you mentioned 'Cannot inject @Test annotated Method' comes because we cannot give params to @Test method, but with dataProvider only.

I think you are missing call for dataProvider in your 2nd @Test annotation in firstClass file, which you are doing fine on 1st @Test annotation.

Comment: Can I use two data providers with different names in 1st @ Test annotation?

Comment: No, one dataProvider can be associated with one annotation only.

Comment: How to call for dataprovider in my 2nd @Test annotation in firstClass file? Give me a example how to do that.

Comment: Please check you 2nd class's 1st test annotation, same way you can use it to parameterise your test case in first class which is throwing error.

Comment: According to your guidance I have created 1st test annotation in first class. Now it is working thank you.